Reset password on Laravel livewire
The problem is when the sendResetLink() is triggered it shows an error that says: "trying to access array offset on value of type null"
the component {
public $email;

public function sendResetLink()
    {
        $this->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email',
        ]);

        try {
            $status = Password::sendResetLink(['email' => $this->email]);

            if ($status === Password::RESET_LINK_SENT) {
                session()->flash('success', 'Reset password link sent successfully.');
                $this->email = '';
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            session()->flash('error', 'Unable to send reset password link.');
        }
    }

}
in the laravel documentation, the function accepts an array and returns a string.
the function in the doc:
$request->validate(['email' => 'required|email']);

$status = Password::sendResetLink(
    $request->only('email')
);

I am 100% sure that the array is not null because I tried to add it manually like this:
dd($this->email); // it return the email i entered from the form 

$credentials = ['email' => $this->email];

$status = Password::sendResetLink($credentials); // and still says its null 


I don't see any code here that could possibly generate that error message. What line is referenced by the message? It's probably coming from somewhere else.
